# Return a Stream Filtered by a Predicate From a Zipper

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have written code that finds the first [equilibrium index](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Equilibrium_index) using zipper + comonad:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val in = NonEmptyList(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0)
in.toZipper
  .cobind { z => z.lefts.sum == z.rights.sum }
  .findNext(identity)
  .map(_.index)

// returns Some(3)
// I would like to return Some(3, 6) or even a scalaz stream?
```

How can I adapt this to return all the equilibrium indices instead of simply the first?

Comment: Also, I am concerned that the algorithmic complexity of this is larger than O(n), what it should be for solving this specific problem.

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97159/stream-combinators-efficiency

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
in.toZipper
  .cobind { z => z.lefts.sum == z.rights.sum }
  .toStream
  .zipWithIndex
  .filter(_._1)
  .map(_._2)
```

But I don't think its performance is very good (due to the repeated summing of the sublists)

Answer (score 1):

I can not help you with your scalaz solution, but a simpler solution to find the equilibrium indices could be:

```
def equilibriaIndices(numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  // sum numbers left side, sum numbers right side, indices equilibiria 
  val startAcc = (0, numbers.sum, List.empty[Int])
  val (_, _, equilibria) = numbers.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(startAcc) { 
    case ((sumLeft, sumRight, indices), (x, index)) => 
      val newIndices = if (sumLeft == sumRight - x) index :: indices else indices
      (sumLeft + x, sumRight - x, newIndices)
  }
  equilibria.reverse
}
```

Which would give you:

```
scala> equilibriaIndices(List(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0))
res5: List[Int] = List(3, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to write an O(n) solution with `Zipper` and `cobind`. However, it is easy to come up with a solution without `Zipper` (but still functional):

```
val in = NonEmptyList(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0).list

val total = in.sum

in
  .scan(0)(_ + _)
  .zip(in)
  .map { case (leftSum, focus) => leftSum == total - leftSum - focus }
  .zipWithIndex
  .filter(_._1)
  .map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution:

```
val in = Stream(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0)
val sum = in.scan(0)(_ + _)
val hash = (in zip sum) map { case (e, lsum) => 2*lsum + e }
val target = sum.last
hash.zipWithIndex.collect { case (e, i) if e == target => i }
```

This solution has O(n) runtime, and it has no dependency on scalaz.

It also has the advantage of not having to precalculate the total sum.

Comment: Doesn't using`hash.last` (which is O(n)) inside your `collect` make this O(n^2) ?

Comment: You are right, I have made an edit. Do you think its possible to improve on this solution?

Comment: Now you are of course precalculating the total sum with `val target = hash.last`. I don't think this solution can be improved very mutch performance wise.

Comment: The only thing I can think of improving is switching the collection to make `hash.last` O(1). Its too bad I must use `target` here and make another traversal.

Comment: Calculating the sum (using `_.sum` or `hash.last`) will always be O(n), even if you access it in O(1) using a different collection, right ?

Comment: You're right that even if the lookup was O(1), the entire algorithm would still be O(n) since the complexity is subsumed by the traversal, but as a minor optimization it would be nice to perform the algorithm in a single pass of the collection

Comment: I meant that calculating the total sum is also O(n), even if you access it in O(1).

Comment: Um, this is not a solution at all.  It works for the example input by a sheer fluke.  Consider that the equality indexes in the example input are obviously also valid in `Stream(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0, -1, 1)`.  Yet @beefyhalo 's code would return `(7, 8)` rather than the correct `(3, 6)`.  This is a nonsense solution.

Comment: Oh, now that makes sense.